# Vector Coordinates

Tags: geometry, vectors

I need to plot a vector onto a Cartesian plane. I have the vector magnitude and the vector angle, in relation to the y-axis (which can be larger than 90°). One of the ends of the vector will always be at $(0, 0)$. How can I calculate the coordinates for the other end of the vector?

Comment: Do you know about polar co-ordinates? If not, see this(it has all you need to answer your question yourself): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about forming a triangle with respect to the y-axis. Then use basic geometric equations for the coordinates.

Look at this image:
[image]

You were provided C, and the angle from B to C. This is just a simple triangle. To find the coordinates, you are simply finding B and A. These can be found by:

$$A=Csin(\theta)$$
$$B=Ccos(\theta)$$

Comment: Curious why B to C is the angle and not A to C? (As with  trig problems)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer In the question, he states his given angle is "in relation to the y-axis". If it was in relation to the x-axis it would indeed be from A to C

Comment: I missed that. +1 for clear answer and for kind response.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this at first and implemented it in the application I'm building. But the thing is I can have angles larger than 90°, and then I won't have a right triangle anymore. I also understand I could use another axis to calculate the triangle, but I'm looking for an all in one formula to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: @renke Actually, you can still use this! The great thing about the $sin$ and $cos$ function is that they are cyclic! So long as the angle is always in relation to the y-axis, the formula's will output what is expected, regardless of $\theta$! $\theta$ can even be over 360!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\sin(\theta)= \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$